# Why is the formal negation of "Somebody trusts Everybody", "∀ person x, ∃ a person y such that x does not trust y"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Converting

> *somebody trusts everybody*

into a formal statement seems to give

> *∃ a person x such that ∀ person y, x trusts y.*

However, my question arises when we attempt to negate this formal statement. If we negate this formal statement, we get:

> *∀ person x, ∃ a person y such that x does not trust y,*

but this seems to contradict the original informal statement as I don't see how you can use "∀ person x" when "somebody" can only refer to one person.

Comment: To negate "somebody", you have to rule out everybody.

Comment: Everybody is untrusting somebody. Or: Nobody trusts everybody.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC But wouldn't somebody refer to a specific person? If you negate "somebody trusts everybody", wouldn't it be "There is someone that that somebody (the same specific person) doesn't trust"?

Comment: "somebody" does not refer to a specific person.  If the original statement was "Bob trusts everybody" then the negation would indeed be "there is a person whom Bob  distrusts", but that's a different claim.

Comment: "Somebody" even in colloquial usage creates an existential quantifier at least within that one sentence, which can then get instantiated and used in a later sentence. Still within the sentence it's introduced it means "there exists a person such that..."

Comment: By the way, the English sentence "somebody trusts everybody" is ambiguous about the order of the quantifiers. We could reasonably interpret it as either $\forall y\exists x T(x,y)$ ("everyone has a truster") or $\exists x\forall y T(x,y)$ ("there is an all-trusting person").

Comment: @Karl As a native speaker of American English, I would require a very specific tone/emphasis in order to interpret "somebody trusts everybody" as "everybody has a truster". I don't think you're technically wrong here, but at least in print I would almost always read it the second way without overwhelming contextual details to suggest the first way. There are certainly examples in English where I would say there is quantifier order ambiguity, even in print. "Any" provides a huge pile of them.

Comment: @Karl - native English speaker here too. I cannot come up with any emphasis or context that would make me interpret that phrase in the first way.

Comment: @hifromdev - "But wouldn't somebody refer to a specific person". No. In fact, that is precisely what it doesn't do. The reason we use "there exists..." is for the situation when we don't know which specific thing something is true for, only that there does exist at least one.

Comment: I'm a native speaker too and agree that in this case without context we're inclined to put the quantifiers in the order that the corresponding words appear, but it's worth noting that this is by no means a rule. Consider e.g. "we've got something for everyone".

Comment: The scopes of variables are different (as well as the order in which the variables are quantified), and thinking of the intended meaning of each statement, the scopes of "somebody" are different in "somebody trusts everybody" and "everybody does not trust somebody".